# How do you set the precedence when combining AND and OR conditions in Exposed?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

If I have a complex where condition in SQL like

`WHERE  A < 2 AND (( B == null OR C > 3) AND (D > 4 OR E < 2))`

How do I express this in Kotlin's Exposed framework?

I see the where has decorators
`.andWhere` and `.orWhere` which I presume keeps them all at the same level of precedence instead of a custom level. I couldn't find any documentation or answers on SO regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have table object named `Table` this query can look like this:

```kotlin
Table.select {
    Table.a.less(2)
        .and(
            Table.b.isNull().or(Table.c.greater(3))
                .and(Table.d.greater(4).or(Table.e.less(2)))
        )
}
```

Operations list may be useful for you https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DSL#where-expression.